# KineticJS; use buttons to make multiple objects appear and disappear

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am new to KineticJS and I am trying to figure out how to make different items appear or disappear with buttons. Below are JSFiddles with examples.

There are four boxes. I want to make it so that when I click on the button for a box, the box appears and any other box that was visible disappears.

In the first JSFiddle, I used addEventListener and individually listed all four squares, setting them to the right opacities. And it works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/T8m64/85/

However, the project I actually want to implement this in has 30 items instead of four. So my question is if there is a faster way to group the items together instead of listing them out. I tried this with Kinetic.Group, but it doesn't seem to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/T8m64/86/

My code for the button event is:

```
    document.getElementById('s1').addEventListener('click', function() {
        square.setOpacity(1);       
        layer.draw();
    }, false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so I don't know much about KineticJS, but I think you can achieve what you want with plain old JavaScript.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrexroad/Vv9kV/29/) that shows one way to do what you want.

The basic idea here is that you set up all of your buttons to have one common class name. Then, using `document.getElementsByClassname` you can get an array of button elements. I used the id of each button to describe the resulting square's desired location in a row/column layout (e.g. id="1_0" is row one, column zero; id="0_1" is row zero, column one).

Then all you have to do is loop over the array and attach the KineticJS shape object and an event listener.

In the KineticJS shape I defined a drawFunc that references a variable for the box coordinates. This variable must be something that does not change (i.e. you don't over write it each time the loop iterates.) The best thing to do for this is somehow attach the coordinates to the shape object. I chose to calculate the row and column for each box and attach them to the object. Then there are some calculations in drawFunc that reference the row/col of the box to calculate the corner coordinates. There are undoubtedly better ways to do it, but I am tired.

Now you can create as many buttons in HTML as you want and they will create boxes based the location specified in their ID.

Comment: I like this solution, but I would use the built in constructor for creating rectangles http://jsfiddle.net/Vv9kV/32/

Comment: also, in case you need to attach/detach the item from the layer, rather than just hide it: http://jsfiddle.net/Xfd6t/

Comment: This solution worked really well. The key was to create an array of the buttons and attach each square to the button. It took me a while to figure out because the objects I'm actually using have no pattern in either location or shape. I realize I wasn't clear in my question: I can't avoid defining each shape individually, but I wanted to avoid listing them again in each button to make things appear and disappear. So this method was awesome: http://jsfiddle.net/T8m64/87/ Thanks Warren!

Comment: I noticed the fiddle is no longer working, so I updated it with the latest version of KineticJS: http://jsfiddle.net/T8m64/233/